# What could the acceleration $2g$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

[image]

The question asked to find the acceleration of each of the three masses. The acceleration of mass A was:

$a$=$2g M_B M_C$/($4$$M_A M_B$+$ M_B M_C$+$ M_A M_C$)

When I supposed   $M_A$=$0$,

$a=2g$

What does this result try to imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to look at mass $M_{\rm A}\rightarrow 0$ or $M_{\rm A} \ll M_{\rm B}, M_{\rm C}$.

In that case the acceleration of mass $M_{\rm B}$ is very small compared with that of mass $M_{\rm A}$ and so mass $M_{\rm B}$ can be thought of a virtually not accelerating at all (or essential fixed in position).

Mass $M_{\rm C}$ is virtually unconstrained because $M_{\rm C} \gg M_{\rm A}$ and so accelerate down at very slightly less than $g$ and this will be the acceleration of the massless pulley.

Since mass $M_{\rm B}$ hardly accelerates at all and the pulley accelerates at almost $g$, the mass $M_{\rm A}$ accelerates at slightly less than $2g$.